# Accessing content in a TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am populating a TableLayout (i.e. rows and columns) with data (strings).

When I click on a cell, I would like the data stored in this cell to be displayed in my console.

How can I do that? Is there any other way than to go over IDs?

Comment: What on earth is this question about?  iPhone?  The space shuttle?

Comment: sorry, it's about development in Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html , there is no Column or TD (Table Data) or Cell equivalent in android. Each element is treated as an individual cell unless otherwise noted.

Having this in mine, and given the fact that you don't specify what kind of View you're using inside your rows, may I guess it's a Button which you can of course click with something like this:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.oneOfMyButtons); // You could create this "on the go"
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){
        System.out.println(v.getText());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although I'm not using buttons, but TextViews, thanks to your help I figured out how to get the data out of the cells. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`TableLayout` extends `LinearLayout`, which do not have an `OnItemClickListener` method. You will need to implement `OnClickListener` in the child `View`s instead.

What you can do instead is to use a `GridView`, that implements `AdapterView` and thus you can use `OnItemClickListener`

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29

```
abstract void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

> Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I tried using a GridView, which however is not exactly what I need for my app.